# Apache2 require authentication for directory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http-authentication

I'm trying to secure my phpmemcachedadmin installation. (It doesn't come with any sort of security, not even a login system)

I've added this to the .htaccess file:

```
AuthName "For admins only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/phpmemcachedadmin/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require user myuser
```

But it doesn't work. Am I missing something here?
The files are owned by www-data, so it can't be a permissions thing.

Comment: Is access allowed or denied?  What error does your browser show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `AllowOverride all` in the vhost config for this directory?
AFAIK this is required.
I would also change the user to `require valid-user`

Comment: That's it, I somehow thought that was the default setting, but even then in said "None" in the httpd.conf file. Thanks